# C++ 複数の派生クラスのオブジェクト生成

Tags: c++

vehicleを基底クラスとした、２つの派生クラスbicycle motorcar、またbicycle とmotorcarを基底クラスとした派生クラスmotorcycle を用意しました。これら５つのオブジェクトをそれぞれ５つだけ生成したいのですが、vehicle が２回生成されてしまいます。どのようにすれば良いのか教えてください。

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class vehicle{
    public:
        vehicle(){cout <<"vehicle Construct" << endl;}
        virtual ~vehicle(){cout << "vehicle Destroy" << endl;}
};
class bicycle : public vehicle{
    public:
        bicycle(){cout << "bicycle Construct" << endl;}
        virtual ~bicycle(){cout << "bicycle Destroy" << endl;}
};
class motorcar : public vehicle{
    public:
        motorcar(){cout << "motorcar Construct" << endl;}
        virtual ~motorcar(){cout << "motorcar Destroy" << endl;}
};
class motorcycle : public bicycle, public motorcar{
    public:
        motorcycle(){cout << "motorcycle Construct" << endl;}
        ~motorcycle(){cout << "motorcycle Destroy" << endl;}
};
int main()
{
    motorcycle mymotorcycle;
    return 0;
}
```

**出力**

```
vehicle Construct
bicycle Construct
vehicle Construct
motorcar Construct
motorcycle Construct
motorcycle Destroy
motorcar Destroy
vehicle Destroy
bicycle Destroy
vehicle Destroy
```

**目標**

```
vehicle Construct
bicycle Construct
motorcar Construct
motorcycle Construct
motorcycle Destroy
motorcar Destroy
bicycle Destroy
vehicle Destroy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bicycle`と`motorcar`に、それぞれの親の`vehicle`がいて別物なので、別々にコンストラクタが呼ばれています。親クラスをまとめるには`virtual`な継承を使います。

```
class bicycle : virtual public vehicle{
    // 略
};
class motorcar : virtual public vehicle{
    // 略
};
```

このように`virtual`を付けた親クラスは全部一つにまとめられます。

---

ただ`virtual`な継承はオーバーヘッドが大きく、パフォーマンスが悪くなりがちなので、使わないで済むように設計するのが普通だと思います。

Comment: なるほど！わかりやすい回答ありがとうございます。